# Swift - Is it possible to animate background image of UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I need to change background image of button several times, I would like to use sequence of images to change background on click but I couldn't find any Swift documentation.

Maybe someone knows how to do that ?

Comment: No its not possible. But you can use imageview.

Comment: Wrong. A UIButton has an imageView, therefore it is possible

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the way.

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i ++) {
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]]];
}

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton.imageView setAnimationImages:[imageArray copy]];
[myButton.imageView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[myButton.imageView startAnimating];
```

Call startAnimating method in on click method.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift:

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()
for var index = 0; index < num; ++index {
    imageArray.append( UIImage(named: "imageNumber\(index)" )! )
}

myButton.setImage( UIImage(named: "imageNumber1")! ), forState: .Normal)
myButton.imageView!.animationImages = imageArray
myButton.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
myButton.imageView!.startAnimating()
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a delay on this? I am trying to animate filling stars and between filling the stars, moving to next question and resetting the star buttons back to empty star images happens too fast and I don't even see the stars filling animation.